# creating a text file name varying everytime it runs in C

Tags: c, file-handling

I wanted to know whether there is a piece of code that can help me with making a new file with a different name every time the function with that code runs, for instance I want to write this

```
FILE * new_file = fopen("D:\C\data\1.txt", "w +" );
```

as

```
FILE * new_file = fopen("D:\C\data\%d.txt", next_number,  "w +" );
```

that next_number comes from another procedure which always will get the number following a number stored in a different file.

Comment: First of all, back-slashes in a string needs to be escaped. Secondly, no that's not a possible way to use `fopen` (you can't just make up your own arguments). Thirdly, you do know about e.g. `snprintf` (or at least `sprintf`)?

Comment: `char buf[256] = ""; sprintf (buf, "D:\\C\\data\\%d.txt", next_number); FILE *new_file = fopen (buf, "w");`  (do you really need `"w+"`?)

Comment: Oh, and `"w +"`? With a *space*? There might be some `fopen` implementations which allow it, but it's non-standard (I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `snprintf()`.

Example:

```
char file_name[100]; // assuming path length is at most 100
snprintf(file_name, sizeof(file_name), "D:\\C\\data\\%d.txt", next_number);
FILE * new_file = fopen(file_name,  "w+" );
```

Comment: Better use `sizeof file_name` as the size. And escape those back-slashes (or use forward slashes).

Comment: Good catch on the escapes -- this looks like windoze.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Edited. Had completely missed the escaping.